# Format Now() to yyyymmdd for date serialization when exporting a PDF

Tags: ms-access, vba

How do I simply format the now() function to a string to name a file that needs a date in it so I don't over write files when I export them?
My reason for asking is I need to export a report to a PDF and I need the name of the PDF in the file location to be:

```
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, _
     "Issue_invsnapshotR", acFormatPDF, _
     "\\SPFS1\Stone\Quality\Support Docs\Issues\" & _
    [issue_id] & _
    "\inv_snapshot_for_issue_" & _
    Me.issue_id & _
    "_on_" & _
    ???yyyymmdd function??? & _    <-----unknown function here
    ".pdf", _
    False, _
    "", , acExportQualityPrint
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unknown function is this:

```
                   Format(now(), "yyyymmdd")
```

The finished code looks like this:

```
     DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, _
     "Issue_invsnapshotR", acFormatPDF, _
     "\\SPFS1\Stone\Quality\Support Docs\Issues\" & _
    [issue_id] & _
    "\inv_snapshot_for_issue_" & _
    Me.issue_id & _
    "_on_" & _
    Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & _
    ".pdf", _
    False, _
    "", , acExportQualityPrint
```

this function will return a string of (today being 3/8/17) 20170308. which can be used to serialize files and folders.